# How do i get boxes to have equal width always

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here i have to boxes, it looks like this

```html
<div class="dataViewBox">
  <div class="dataViewBox-Download">
    <div class="dataViewBox-DownloadLink">
      <span class="dataViewBox-Hashes"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="testblock0h" class="dataViewBox-HideShowButton" onclick="magicmushrooms('testblock0')">Show</div>

    <div class="dataViewBox-Name">SomeName</div>
  </div>

  <div id="testblock0" class="dataViewBox-BottomBorder">
    <div id="test0" class="dataViewBox-Data toggleable Text">
        <span>this is just a test to show the the box can expand and be alot more bigger then it first was</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="infoViewExpirein">
  <div id="infoViewExpireinTime">Build this up to be bigger then the box................................</div>
</div>

<div class="dataViewBox">
  <div class="dataViewBox-Download">
    <div class="dataViewBox-DownloadLink">
      <span class="dataViewBox-Hashes"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="testblock1h" class="dataViewBox-HideShowButton" onclick="magicmushrooms('testblock1')">Show</div>

    <div class="dataViewBox-Name">SomeName</div>
  </div>

  <div id="testblock1" class="dataViewBox-BottomBorder">
    <div id="test1" class="dataViewBox-Data toggleable Text">
        <span>See how this box fallows the other one when you open it, and same when you close it, it always has equal width</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="infoViewExpirein">
  <div id="infoViewExpireinTime">Build this up to be bigger then the box................................</div>
</div>
```

All the code is too much to post here, but I have two boxes, the code works as it is now but the thing is that I do not like how I have solved this problem, if you open one box and you'll see at the other comes free with and the same size, it's the idea that it should be so. So all elements on the page is always symmetric. Its just that it only works if you have "display: table" in body. And i try to find another way to do this whit same results, its always hard when you try to get equal width on everything, But the way to do it CSS/JavaScript does not matter

Link: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xuee3/)

/ Slaktarn

Comment: I don't really see a question... So what do you want?

Comment: sorry, couldn't understand the problem.... I'm seeing the equal width boxes...

Comment: Do same thing when not use "display: table" in the body, of some reason i wrote "display: block" but it is "display: table"

Comment: @Whiskey Just wrap it in a `div` and set it on that... [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xuee3/1/)

Comment: Actually i think the question was how to do this and not use table, if that is possible! The table when you wrap everything mess some stuff up, but its nice as it always have equal width and is very dynamic that way.

Comment: You have posted this question before, I know this because I was trying to answer it. Please do not post the same question 2 times.

Comment: Ruddy, the answer is not in the other post!

Comment: @Whiskey: so? That's not a valid reason to re-post a question. There *never* is a valid reason to repost a question.

Comment: Maybe not, but its stupid to post that the answer is there when its not

Comment: @Whiskey I didn't say the answer was there. I said I tried to answer the question. Learn to read.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add a max-width parameter to whatever elements you want to limit in size.

```
body {
   ...
   display: block;
   max-width: 450px;
}
```

Comment: I was not after to limit the size, i was after to  it is now, Just that all elements fallows the biggest elemedo same thing as i do know but not whit table and not whit size limit asnt, and im not sure any other things can do the automatic, and i try whit the display block, it brakes everything, if you look at that edit and the code i provided, the results are not the same